# No fill from ad server. in DFP Banner Ads

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-dfp

Hi i have used latest Google Admob Sdk for DoubleClick For Publishers (DFP) Banner Ads to my App.
    Everything is working fine when run my app without error, but i got logcate message as No fill from ad server and Failed to load ad: 3 and i could not see any ads in my emulator and phone also. what wrong doing, Please tell me if anybody known to handle this kind of problem.

Thanks in Advance.
my code part :

```
adView = (PublisherAdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
// Create an ad request.
 PublisherAdRequest.Builder publisherAdRequestBuilder = 
         new PublisherAdRequest.Builder();

   publisherAdRequestBuilder.
   addTestDevice(PublisherAdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
   publisherAdRequestBuilder.
   addTestDevice("B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB");
   adView.loadAd(publisherAdRequestBuilder.build());

<com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxx"
ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The code 3 (no fill from ad server) basically says that your code is fine but that DfP doesn't have an ad to display at the moment.

Either there is no line item at all for the ad unit, or it has a frequency cap that was hit, or the delivery speed is too low to deliver an ad at the moment, or the targeting is too restrictive or a combination of these factors.

So to fix it, you need change your creatives, line items etc. in DfP and make sure it can deliver an ad. And don't forget it takes a while until changes in DfP become effective.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a publisher has to change the creatives and line items. This question is asked by an app developer, what he has to do with this ?

Comment: If there is a strict separation between publisher and developer (e.g. because they belong to two different companies), then the developer will need to contact the publisher and ask him to add a matching line item.